# Volume parametrisation integral bounds problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, parametrization, multiple-integral

$$\ D = \{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1,\space z\geq {(\sqrt{5}-1)/2} \}$$
I do not understand why the two following parametrisations for the integral of this volume do not give the same result
$$\sigma_1(r,\theta,\phi)=(r\cos\theta \sin\phi,r\sin\theta \sin\phi,r\cos\phi) $$
with $\space0 \leq r\leq 1, \space 0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi, \space 0\leq \phi\leq\arccos((\sqrt{5}-1)/2)$
$$V_1 = \int_0^{\arccos((\sqrt{5}-1)/2))}\int_0^1\int_{0}^ {2\pi} r^2\sin(\phi) d\theta drd\phi \space = \frac\pi3 (3-\sqrt{5})$$ 
$$ $$
$$ \sigma_2(r,\theta,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z) $$
with $ \space0 \leq r\leq \sqrt{1-z^2}, \space 0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi, \space (\sqrt{5}-1)/2\leq z\leq 1 $

$$V_2 = \int_{(\sqrt{5}-1)/2}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_{0}^ {2\pi}r\space  d\theta drdz \space = \frac\pi6 (3-\sqrt{5})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds on $r$ in the first integral is incorrect. This can easily be seen as it ranges from $0$ to $1$, but we shouldn't be including anything of distance less than $(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$ from the origin because $z\geq (\sqrt{5}-1)/2$. The range of $r$ will be even shorter as $\phi$ increases. Try drawing a picture to help you find the exact bounds.

Your second integral is fine.

Comment: okay but if my r bound ranges from $ \frac {\sqrt5-1}2$ to 1 the result is still different

Comment: Spoke to fast.. my r bound must ranges from $ \sqrt{1-(\frac {\sqrt5-1}2)^2}$ to 1 and the result is as wanted

Comment: Interesting find, although that's still not right. Note that since $z$ depends on both $r$ and $\phi$, there is a relationship between the bounds of $r$ and $\phi$ which is not satisfied if both bounds are constant.

Comment: should $r$ be bounded by $0$ and $ \frac {1}{\sqrt {1+cos^2(\phi)}} $ ?

Comment: this comes from substituing the values of my parametrisation into the volume conditions